Vector encoding provider AzureOpenAI is not supported under genai.vector.encode
Vector encoding provider AzureOpenAI is not supported in genai.vector.encode.
Error message below encountered:
ClientError: {code: Neo.ClientError.Procedure.ProcedureCallFailed} {message: Failed to invoke function `genai.vector.encode`: Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Vector encoding provider not supported: AzureOpenAI}    

when calling genai.vector.encode:
# Call on VScode where kg is an instance of my Neo4jGraph`
kg.query("""
    MATCH (chunk:Chunk) 
    WHERE chunk.textEmbedding IS NULL
    WITH chunk, genai.vector.encode(
      chunk.text, 
      "AzureOpenAI", 
      {
        token: $openAiApiKey, 
        resources: $resource,
        deployment: $deployment
      } 
    ) AS vector
    CALL db.create.setNodeVectorProperty(chunk, "textEmbedding", vector)

    """, 
    params={"openAiApiKey":OPENAI_API_KEY, "resource":RESOURCE, "deployment":DEPLOYMENT})

# Call on Neo4j Desktop App
    MATCH (chunk:Chunk) 
    WHERE chunk.textEmbedding IS NULL
    WITH chunk, genai.vector.encode(
      chunk.text, 
      "AzureOpenAI", 
      {
        token: xxxxx, 
        resources: xxxxx
        deployment: "embedding"
      } 
    ) AS vector
    CALL db.create.setNodeVectorProperty(chunk, "textEmbedding", vector)
  

- Neo4j version: 5.18.1
- Edition: enterprise
- Operating system: MacOS Sonoma 14.1
- API/Driver: both VSCode and Neo4j desktop App
I have checked the version of my Neo4j and Apoc and met the requirements for both. My database on VScode has been successfully connected and the rest of the queries work as normal, e.g. `MATCH (n) RETURN n` on Desktop App, `print(kg.schema)` on VScode. The initialisation on VScode is done by calling method provided by langchain:
from langchain_community.graphs import Neo4jGraph 
kg = Neo4jGraph(url=NEO4J_URI, username=NEO4J_USERNAME, password=NEO4J_PASSWORD, database=NEO4J_DATABASE )

Could anyone please help me solve this provider issue?

your genai plugin should be the same version as your neo4j, 5.18 in your case.
